# Deleted home folder keeps coming back

Tags: linux, linux-mint, home

In Linux Mint 20.3, even after `reboot` and as `sudo su` root from `/home/admin` user with `deluser cees` and `userdel cees` not finding user `cees`, `/home/cees` keeps reappearing after `rm -rf /home/cees`. Users and Groups doesn't show `cees` either. How to remove `/home/cees` permanently?

Comment: As root try `rm -rf /home/cees; mkdir /home/cees; chmod 000 /home/cees; chattr +i /home/cees`. Then reboot and look for errors from software trying access that directory. You will need to *chattr -i /home/cees* to be able to delete it later. Also `find /etc/ -type f -exec grep -H cees {} \;` might show something.

Comment: The command `rm -rf cees` does nothing unless `$PWD` is `/home`. You should specify full path: `rm -rf /home/cees`.

Comment: @fuzzydrawings It is, hence "coming back". I'll clarify the question.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman "Coming back" could mean you ran the command, saw the directory was still there, and assumed it "came back". You should clarify that the directory was indeed gone (ie, by showing output of `ls /home`).

Comment: @fuzzydrawings I would, but i'm cleaning a work laptop and didn't feel like logging in or making a photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [CR.'s comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693154/deleted-home-folder-keeps-coming-back?noredirect=1#comment1310871_693154), as root in two terminals, i ran `rm -rf /home/cees && mkdir /home/cees && chmod 000 /home/cees && chattr +i /home/cees` and `tail -f /var/log/syslog` to see that `restartmanger` is the process attempting to create a `kafka` folder in `/home/cees`.
Indeed `docker image ls` lists `bitname/kafka`. `docker image rm bitnami/kafka` after `docker container rm container_id_using_kafka` helped.